# changing the initial viewcontroller in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to find out if its possible to change the initial storyboards viewcontroller by code.

For example:

App launches --> Viewcontroller A loads --> user makes some interactions --> code get executed --> Viewcontroller B loads

Next time the app launches --> Viewcontroller B loads

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save some indicator that says you want to go to B on launch and, if that's true go to the "code get executed --> Viewcontroller B loads" section.

Comment: so its not possible to change the IB flag "is Initial View Controller" by code?

Comment: Whether you can or not, the problem is going to be trying to write back a change into your app bundle (on a device) so that it takes effect on next launch.  Those are readonly.

Comment: The easiest way is probably `NSUserDefaults` (unless you're already using configuration files or Core Data for other things).  Take a look at Apple's "DrillDownSave" sample code; it seems close to what you want.